# Error gradle on mfp cordova run -p android

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-cli, mobilefirst-cli

I have an error with MobileFirst Foundation 7.1, when i want to run my application on my device with command : mfp cordova run -p android :

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
mobilefirst-cli verb cordova_run error stack: "Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\r\n\r\n* Where:\r\nBuild file 'C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\build.gradle' line: 3\r\n\r\n* What went wrong:\r\nA problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.\r\n> Gradle version 2.2 is required.
Current version is 1.12. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\gradle\\wrapper\\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip\r\n\r\n* Try:\r\nRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.\r\n\r\nC:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\cordova\\node_modules\\q\\q.js:126\r\n                    throw e;\r\n                          ^\r\nError code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\gradlew,build,-b,C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalRelease,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint\n    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\MobileFirst-CLI\\mobilefirst-cli\\node_modules\\cordovacmd\\lib\\cordova-cli.js:253:41)\n    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)\nat maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)\n    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)"
mobilefirst-cli verb cordova_run error message: "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\r\n\r\n* Where:\r\nBuild file 'C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\build.gradle' line: 3\r\n\r\n* What went wrong:\r\nA problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.\r\n> Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.12. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\gradle\\wrapper\\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip\r\n\r\n* Try:\r\nRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.\r\n\r\nC:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\cordova\\node_modules\\q\\q.js:126\r\n                    throw e;\r\n                          ^\r\nError code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\gradlew,build,-b,C:\\projects\\profondeur\\trunk\\platforms\\android\\build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalRelease,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint"
mobilefirst-cli verb cordova_run error code: 0
Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.12. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\platforms\android\gradlew,build,-b,C:\projects\profondeur\trunk\platforms\android\build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalRelease,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint
mobilefirst-cli verb cli error, finish with mobilefirst cordova
```

I don't understand what the problem is with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file, make sure that you are using the latest gradle plugin version. Currently 1.5.0

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Then go to platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and make sure distributionUrl value is using the latest.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Also I would suggest adding this environment variable so that it will pull the gradle wrapper distribution url version that you want. Cordova tends to add an old version unless you add this environment variable.

CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip

Comment: So I have the good value in build.gralde but not in gradle-wrapper.properties where I have this code :
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip`


Even after i have add this environment variable : CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip

Comment: Manually change `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip` to the correct version in gradle-wrapper.properties to the correct value.

Also, look through parent directories of your project and delete any build.gradle & gradle folder (with the gradle wrapper files inside). Sometimes these get generated. 

ex. C:/User/workspace/myproject/, 
gradle files may be generated in either User directory or workspace directory. You will need to remove those.